# PHP json_decode return array and number key

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following JSON array:

```
[
  {"r1t7pjT4wn":{"Title":"test","Meta":"test","SM_D":"test","BIG_D":"test"}},
  {"3rMlBu6LpZ":{"Title":"test1","Meta":"test1","SM_D":"test1","BIG_D":"test1"}}
]
```

When I do `json_decode`, I expect to see:

```
Array ( 
  "r1t7pjT4wn" => Array ( [Title] => test [Meta] => test [SM_D] => test [BIG_D] => test ),
  "3rMlBu6LpZ" => Array ( [Title] => test1 [Meta] => test1 [SM_D] => test1 [BIG_D] => test1 )
)
```

However, PHP yields:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [r1t7pjT4wn] => Array ( [Title] => test [Meta] => test [SM_D] => test [BIG_D] => test ) ) 
  [1] => Array ( [3rMlBu6LpZ] => Array ( [Title] => test1 [Meta] => test1 [SM_D] => test1 [BIG_D] => test1 ) ) 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

if you can't change source json, add one function call

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge', json_decode($json, true));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your **data** *is* an array!  If it were an *associative* array (*i.e.* if it began with `{` and ended with `}`) then `json_decode` would have the output you expect.

---

Change your JSON to:

```
{
   "r1t7pjT4wn":{"Title":"test","Meta":"test","SM_D":"test","BIG_D":"test"},
   "3rMlBu6LpZ":{"Title":"test1","Meta":"test1","SM_D":"test1","BIG_D":"test1"}
}
```